# 2048 heuristic, unexpected results

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm working an AI for 2048. So far its pretty simple, I'm basically trying to make a "snake" of decreasing tiles, so the perfect game would look like: [image: Perfect game], although that is just as good as this:[image].

My heuristic is using a simple 2d array that multiplies each cell with decreasing magnitude in shape of a shake, like:

```
---------------------
| 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 |
| 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 8  | 7  | 6  | 5  |
| 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
---------------------
```

This works relatively well, it gets to 2048 about half the time, but sometimes it makes really weird decisions, like:

[Suggests right, correct is left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydjo4.png)

[Suggests right, correct is left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4PKe.png)

[Suggests down, correct is left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00kBH.png)

[Suggests down, correct is left/right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4nzd.png)

Is it possible to adjusts the weights or add some sort of penalty to penalize this behavior? Everything else works fine, and even mathematically some of these don't make any sense. F.ex. #3 is obviously better off to the left than down, the largest multiplicand is in the corner, and merging a 256 to the corner should produce the best result?

EDIT:

```
def getBestMove(node, depth):
    bestValue, bestAction = -1, None
    for direction in xrange(4):
        temp, score, moved = Board.move(node, direction)
        if not moved: continue
        val = minimax(temp, depth - 1, False)
        if val > bestValue:
            bestValue = val
            bestAction = direction
    return bestValue, bestAction


def minimax(node, depth, maximizingPlayer):
    if depth == 0:
        return heuristic(node)
    elif Board.isLost(node):
        return 0

    if maximizingPlayer:
        bestValue = -1
        for direction in xrange(4):
            temp, score, moved = Board.move(node, direction)
            if not moved: continue
            val = minimax(temp, depth - 1, False)
            if val > bestValue: bestValue = val
        return bestValue
    else:
        bestValue = 1<<20
        for cell in Board.getFreeCells(node):
            for cellValue in [2, 4]:
                temp = deepcopy(node)
                temp[cell[0]][cell[1]] = cellValue

                val = minimax(temp, depth - 1, True)
                if val < bestValue: bestValue = val
        return bestValue
```

Is the basic implementation of minimax that I use. The heuristic function as described is a simple multiplication of 2D arrays. One is the board itself, the other is the mask, there are a total of 4 masks, which is just that "snake" with decreasing numbers starting in the four different corners:

```
def heuristic(board):
    return max([mulArr(board, grid) for grid in grids])


def mulArr(arr1, arr2):
    return sum([arr1[i][j]*arr2[i][j] for i in xrange(len(arr1)) for j in xrange(len(arr1))])
```

Comment: Detect the cases where correct is left and heuristic says right and adjust it.

Comment: That is exactly what I need help, I added examples of where the heuristic gives unexpected results, and I don't know how to adjust it to make it work. Setting higher weights will prioritize the largest tiles and ignore the smaller ones, this will ruin the structure. If you keep weights down, then making a small incorrect move wont be punishing enough to prevent it. Clearly I need an additional heuristic on top of the current.

Comment: Can you explain more how your algorithm choose a solution, like for one of your example, the score of each posibilities (Up, Down, Left, Right). That will help us to understand better your algorithm and optimize it!

Comment: I added the code in the edit. Basically its a straight forward implementation of minimax, and the heuristic is the 2D array multiplication of the different "masks".

Comment: Minimax is not fit for this problem. Minimax should be used for a 2 players games. In your case, you should always be in the case maximizingPlayer = True... In your case, you should do a Depth-first search.

Comment: And I'm not sure that search to deeply is a good solution as you should simulate the add of new randoms cells on the board.
An heuristic with a deep of 1 should give you good solutions too

Comment: If, somewhere in your code, you have an array of possible moves like this: `["right", "down", "left", "up"]`, then you could try reprioritizing moves in case of a tie by rearranging the array: `["left", "up", "right", "down"]`. the same idea may hold even without an array structure like this... just reprioritize moves in case of a tie between multiple moves.

Comment: While it is debatable whether minimax is the best option (vs. expectimax), I don't follow your argument... maximizingPlayer is not always true, you can treat the random element of the game (Where and what tile will spawn after your move) as the opponent, expect that it will place the tile at the worst possible spot for you.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja This wont help as its not a problem of a tie, it clearly picks other direction ahead. I need some sort of counter weight to my basic mask

Comment: @Gabz I did try with depth 1, the program is unable to plan ahead and simply does greedy merges which makes a terrible structure that loses the game with an average max tile of 64. At depth 3-4 it manages 2048 tile 50% of the time

Comment: @Limonup : I not read well your code, Minmax is a good choice yes! I think we should work on your heuristic, I will think about it!

Comment: What I think is your problem, is that the algorithm that plans a given amount of moves ahead always places an imaginary block after each imaginary move randomly. It then chooses the move that ended up in the best situation after `n` moves. It's likely that in the examples you provided the algorithm had thought that after doing the seemingly bad move, the move will eventually result in a very good situation. This of course fails because the actual block that will be placed after the move is unlikely in the same position as in the planning-ahead. Hope you could follow.

Comment: I think I follow you, but some of these don't really make a sense. F.ex. the example #3, I cant think of any sequence of 3 moves that would make the best choice to go down. If you go down, you cant place the 128+128 in any corner in 3 moves. Clearly the only right move should be to go to the left.

That being said, what Im asking for is to have additional function as part of my heuristic that will punish these types of moves. The current heuristic works well for about 80% of the cases, need just some additional function that will force it to stay in formation.

Comment: Maybe you're not emphasizing the importance of having the biggest number on the top left, and thus your algorithm thought that by doing *this*, there are *more* blocks in the correct order. Try a heuristic like this (snakeing from top left to bottom right): `34 33 32 31 24 23 22 21 14 13 12 11 4 3 2 1`

Answer (score 0):

For your heuritic, can you try :

```
| 32768 16384 8192 4096 |
|  256   512  1024 2048 |
|  128    64   32   16  |
|   1     2     4    8  |
```

And find the minimum?

Comment: Results: With min the mean max tile is 64. Same mask, but with max has a mean of 256. The problem with this is that the numbers are so big that getting the max tile right will basically neutralize the other cells. With this heuristic, it often forms a pattern like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oce4N.png, instead of the "snake". This is less efficient and will often block for further progress.

I think the right way to go is to use the mask I already have, but to have some other punishing factor. I've been looking at the smoothness function.

Comment: Ran out of space, the smoothness function is described here: http://artent.net/2014/04/07/an-ai-for-2048-part-4-evaluation-functions/

The idea is that once it is in the snake pattern, it will be expensive to break out of it as the non-smoothness will increase.